# Sign a document in Java and verify it in C#

Tags: c#, java, cryptography

We are going to sign documents on a Linux server using Java and then verify the document and signature on a Windows PC using C#.  What is the best way to do this?

In Java I tried  generating the key pair using a KeyGenerator:

```
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "SUN");

keyGen.initialize(256, random);

KeyPair pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
PublicKey publicKey = pair.getPublic();
System.out.println(" Encoding: " + publicKey.getFormat());

FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("privateKey.dat");
out.write(publicKey.getEncoded());
out.close();
```

The console shows that the format of the key is X.509. I then tried reading the public key into C# with the call:

```
X509Certificate cert= X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(m_fileName);
```

This throws the exception:  CryptographicException: Cannot find the requested object.  Any suggestions on how to accomplish this task will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you have only written the public key **part** of X5.09, which is really nothing more than the PKCS#1 encoding of the public key. To create a full X5.09 certificate you need special software, or you should create it with another tool such as the OpenSSL command line. You could create certificates within the code using the Bouncy Castle libraries. You should think very well how you want store and use your private key first though (key management).

Note that rather than going for a low level format it would probably be better to create a CMS (Cryptographic Message Syntax) signature. You could even use a detached signature. The CMS container format is supported by both the [C#](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) and the [Java](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) versions of the [Bouncy Castle libraries](http://www.bouncycastle.org/). Alternatively you could opt for a PGP signature created by the same libraries.

Comment: Note that a complete walk through of the process is asking for a bit too much, please ask separate questions (after checking this site) if you get stuck.

Comment: Anything specific that is missing from my answer, AlanM?

Comment: I see what you mean that the certificate isn't complete.  I posed a new question where I used keytool to generate public/private key pair and to export a certificate.  I read the certificate in C# and tried to create a CNG key.  Please see [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599278/validate-a-signed-document-in-c-sharp-signed-with-ec-with-key-from-a-self-signed

Comment: Yes, but is there anything missing from my answer?